# Hi everyone, could anyone help me understand how two cylindrical lens can be used to form a laser sheet?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, lenses, optical-materials

If you look at the below link under 'Laser Sheet',
https://www.edmundoptics.com/campaigns/cylinder-lens/

the equation is much easier for a single line generator. I am stuck at the point where I use a second lens. Say for the sheet, input beam dia is 5mm and working distance L is 100mm, I use 'x = (d/EFL) (L + EFL)' for the 1st lens, then at which distance from the 1st lens do I keep the 2nd lens and how do I choose the FL of the 2nd lens. And how to use 'x = (d/EFL) (L + EFL)' for the 2nd lens (especially about the L part).

Would you be able to help me figure out the equation to be used at both lenses to get the final light sheet? I am literally stuck at the calculation point.

Comment: You did not give any parameters for your desired light-sheet's divergence, so no one can help you choose the second lens, ie your target is unspecified. With your parameters (5mm diam, FL= 100mm) you can calculate the divergence of the long side. From there it is straightforward to calculate for example a required length of the long side as its simple trigonometry. They even give you the formula (x). You treat each axis separately.

Comment: Hi Jose, say for the 1st PCV lens, keeping d as 5mm, fl as 12.5mm and L as 100m, I get x as 45mm. Now for the y axis, how do I go about this same equation? Do I take d as 5mm here also? I am sure as you said it could be a simple trigonometry, but I do appreciate any help here as I am having difficulty in calculating the final sheet dimensions.